# AnsiEsc plugin error

Tags: color

When executing vim, after installing AnsiEsc, I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for "*":
E117: Unknown function: AnsiEsc#BufReadPost
```

Do you know how to fix this? is there any up-to-date alternative to AnsiEsc to highlight ansi escape codes?

Comment: First you should tell us how you installed the plugin (maybe you made a mistake here) and which one you installed (because duckduckgo returns several different repos). Then your best bet is probably to reach to the author directly because it is pretty unlikely that someone will debug this kind of plugin which is not widely used. Maybe you can look at [this fork](https://github.com/powerman/vim-plugin-AnsiEsc) maybe the "minor fixes" mentioned in the readme include your issue. Finally you could look at the sources by yourself and see if you find the unkown function and if it has erros

Comment: @statox, thank you, the code you linked looks a bit less old than the one I've used. I will give a try

Comment: If the fork fixes the issue, please let us know it could be useful for future users. If it does you can answer your own question :)